# The WiFi connection on my Dell XCD 35 (Froyo) times out

Tags: 2.2-froyo, wi-fi, connection-issues

I recently bought the Dell XCD35, one of the biggest issues I'm facing is that it keeps disconnecting from an established (and saved) WiFi network and I need to manually select 'Connect' for it to get on WiFi.

I don't have this problem with my Galaxy 3, which I'm also using. And the problem persists even on other WiFi networks that I've tried connecting to. I've checked the settings (WiFi sleep, etc.) Also downloaded WiFi Manager app but no difference.

There is no trouble while connecting, but the moment the screen times out, the Wifi connection does too! This is very annoying, because it used up precious network. Is there a solution or should I just junk this phone?

Comment: So your Wifi sleep policy is set to "Never" but it still disconnects?

Comment: That's right...

Answer (score 0):

There is an application in Google Play named Blade WiFi Fix; it will solve your problem.

Comment: Can you add the link to the app?

Comment: Do you mean this application?  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bladewififix

Answer (score -1):

it happens to my dellxcd too.  i think u cant use both bluetooth and wifi in xcd at same time.